# using arrowkeys in a c# webapp

Tags: javascript, web, arrow-keys

I am trying to make a webapp with c# as code behind. A target is to be able  to change from one  site to another using ***the arrowkeys*** to switch back and forward. I do have a forward- & backwards button which i think would be the easiest to call, because of the fact,that those buttons already do the "page switching thing". I'm pretty new to the whole c# thingy and don't know much about it yet so i would really appreciate if the code suggestions you guys make are commented.

This is the c# code which is most likly used to get the page location and says the button what he has to do. I did not made the code i took over the project from a guy workin in my company thats why I dont know how they have done everything exactly.

```
public class GetPageMeta {

public DataTable lDataTable = new DataTable();
public DataSet lPageDataset;
public SqlDataAdapter lDataAdapter;

public  GetPageMeta()
{
    GetDataSet();
}

private void GetDataSet()
{
    SqlConnection lConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crmmonitorSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    lConnection.Open();

    //lDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T_Pages.ID,T_Pages.CategoryFK,T_Categories.CategoryName,T_Pages.Name,T_Pages.URL,T_Pages.PositionID,T_Pages.DisplayDuration, T_Pages.GraphicsQuant, T_Pages.Description FROM T_Pages LEFT JOIN T_Categories ON T_Pages.CategoryFK = T_Categories.ID ORDER BY T_Pages.PositionID;", lConnection);
    lDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT T_Pages.ID,T_Pages.CategoryFK,T_Pages.Name,T_Pages.URL,T_Pages.PositionID,T_Pages.DisplayDuration, T_Pages.GraphicsQuant, T_Pages.Description FROM T_Pages ORDER BY T_Pages.PositionID;", lConnection);


    lPageDataset = new DataSet("PageDataSet");
    lDataAdapter.FillSchema(lPageDataset, SchemaType.Source, "T_Pages");
    lDataAdapter.Fill(lPageDataset, "T_Pages");
    lDataTable = lPageDataset.Tables["T_Pages"];
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdbld = new SqlCommandBuilder(lDataAdapter);
    lConnection.Close();
}

private void GetGraphicDataSet()
{

}

public DataRow PMetaDataRow(string url)
{
    try
    {
        DataRow PMetaDataRow;
        DataRow[] lMetaDataRow;
        string search = "URL='" + url + "'";

        //lMetaDataRow = lDataTable.Select(search);
        lMetaDataRow = lDataTable.Select("URL='" + url + "'");
        PMetaDataRow = lMetaDataRow[0];

        return PMetaDataRow;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public DataRow PMetaDataRow(int PageID)
{
    try
    {
        DataRow PMetaDataRow;
        DataRow[] lMetaDataRow;
        string search = "ID='" + PageID + "'";

        //lMetaDataRow = lDataTable.Select(search);
        lMetaDataRow = lDataTable.Select("ID='" + PageID + "'");
        PMetaDataRow = lMetaDataRow[0];

        return PMetaDataRow;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the Masterpage file:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Masterpage.master.cs" Inherits="Masterpage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">

        <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="cssreset.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideDiv() {
        if ($(window).width() < 1580) {
            $("#crop2").fadeOut("slow");
        } else {
            $("#crop2").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }

    //run on document load and on window resize
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //on load
        hideDiv();

        //on resize
        $(window).resize(function () {
            hideDiv();
        });

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideDiv2() {
        if ($(window).width() < 1580) {
            $("#crop").fadeOut("slow");
        } else {
            $("#crop").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //on load
        hideDiv2();

        //on resize
        $(window).resize(function () {
            hideDiv2();
        });
    });
</script>

        <title>MY APP</title>
    </head>

    <body  scroll="no">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <div id="logo">
               <a href="/home.aspx">
                <asp:Image ID="Logol_loop_small" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Pictures/logol_loop_small.gif" Border="0"/>
               </a>
            </div>
    <div id="topnav">
            <div class="menu2"> 

            <asp:Menu  ID="mnuContent" runat="server"  Font-Names="Trebuchet MS"
            CssClass="SomeMenuClass"
            Orientation="Horizontal" StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="StaticMenuStyle" DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="DynamicMenuStyle"
            StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="StaticMenuItemStyle" DisappearAfter="1" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
            ForeColor="Black" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" 
            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="10" StaticSubMenuIndent="0px" 
                DynamicHorizontalOffset="1" >
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuStyle" 
                    VerticalPadding="3px" HorizontalPadding="26px" ItemSpacing="0px"></DynamicMenuItemStyle>
            <DynamicMenuStyle Width="300px" CssClass="DynamicMenuStyle" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                <DynamicItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Text") %>
                </DynamicItemTemplate>

            <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="StaticMenuItemStyle" Width="138px" 
                Font-Size="12px" VerticalPadding="13px">
            </StaticMenuItemStyle>
            <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="StaticMenuStyle"></StaticMenuStyle>
            <StaticSelectedStyle Font-Bold="False" VerticalPadding="13px" />
            </asp:Menu> 

            </div>

            <div id="homebutton">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_homebutton" runat="server" />
            </div>
       </div>
        <div id="pagetitel">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_Pagetitel" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        </div>

                 <div id="visualtitel1">
                <h2>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_visualtitel1" runat="server" />
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="visual1">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_visual1" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div id="visualtitel2">
                <h2>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_visualtitel2" runat="server" />
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="visualtitel3">
                <h2>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_visualtitel3" runat="server" />
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div id="visual2">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_visual2" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div id="visual3">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_visual3" runat="server" />
            </div>

        <div id="NextPrevious">

                <div id="zuruekbutton">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_zuruekbutton" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="explanationText">
                   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_explanationText" runat="server" />
                </div>

                <div id="weiterbutton">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_weiterbutton" runat="server"/>    
                </div>

        </div>



            <div id="crop">
                <asp:Image ID="cropleft" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Pictures/crop2.jpg" Width="100%" />
            </div>

            <div id="crop2">
                <asp:Image ID="cropright" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Pictures/crop3.png" ImageAlign="Right" Width="100%"  />
            </div>

            <div id ="footerleft">
                <% lblCopyright.Text = "&#169; Copyright CompanyName" + DateTime.Today.Year + " | MY APP"; %>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCopyright" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div id ="footercenter">
                <asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server"></asp:Label>             
            </div>

            <div id="footerright">
                <%  tbDateTime.Text = DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();   %>
                <asp:Label ID="tbDateTime" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </div>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

the two "buttons" are here:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_weiterbutton" Runat="Server">
    <a ID="ancNext" runat="server" class="standardbutton" target="_self">Weiter</a>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content7" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_zuruekbutton" Runat="Server">
      <a id="ancPrevious" runat="server" class="standardbutton_back" target="_self">Zurück</a>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You will have to implement that in JavaScript, I think...

Comment: Look at javascript and the onkeypress and similar events.

Comment: @Web_dude Treat all the key-press behavior like left/right keys using javascript. I would monitor key press event on this and then navigate to the new url using ajax or just changing the `window.location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript for that by capturing the onkeyup event on the document. 
If you know the keycode of the key that has been pressed you can then make javascript 'click' the corresponding button, anchor or input, that executes the needed functionality.

Here's a small example script that might get you up to speed:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){

    if(!event.keyCode){
        keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
        keycode = event.keyCode;
    }


    switch(keycode){
        //left
        case 37:
        $('#zuruekbutton').find('a, input[type=submit], button').click();
        break;

        //right
        case 39:
        $('#zuruekbutton').find('a, input[type=submit], button').click();
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
};
```

Comment: I now implemented the script into my site but it's giving me a runtime error for the property "click". it says that the values is null or undefined. Do you have a suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: try debugging the document.getElementById('buttonLeftId') part, where 'buttonLeftId' should, ofcourse, be replaced by your own button identifier. If the element can be looked up, the click method will not give you any error messages. If nothing helps, you could also try it with a framework like jQuery, these frameworks have a lot of handy features for solving these issues.

Comment: could it be possible, that there is a difference due the fact that my "button is just a styled div and not a 

<button id="zuruekbutton">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_zuruekbutton" > runat="server" />
 </button>

Comment: Yes, that is a difference. But you do need to have some sort of initiator, like a button or anchor, to execute the needed functionality, that works without javascript? With javascript you can then, almost always, mimic the user input.

Comment: I updated my question now. Maybe you can tell me how i could call this object in javascript or give me another solution.

Comment: Can you show me your view? The ascx or aspx page, where the actual html is generated?

Comment: I updated the question again. thanks for your effort to help me :)

Comment: I have updated the answer with a jQuery lookup. It now searches within the given div's for anchor, input or button (only one of these is needed ofcourse, but I cannot see what's printed in the contentplaceholders of your masterpage).

Comment: sadly this did not work ether. i updated the question again to show you the 2 "buttons" You might know now what I would need to change.